# Take part of string and convert from hex to text javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hex

I have an example string called "Elite%3A%20Dangerous", and as you might be able to see, does it contain 2 different hex symbols, so what I want to do is to convert the string where there's a percentage symbol and the 2 next characters using Javascript, I hope you can help! 
These are not the only hex symbols I'll run in to I believe!

Thanks in advance,
Magn0053

Comment: Use the [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example string looks like an encoded URI component. To decode it, use `decodeURIComponent`.

```
decodeURIComponent('Elite%3A%20Dangerous');
//"Elite: Dangerous"
```

Comment: As soon as possible I'll check if it works, THX though :)

Comment: Very well, but for the title there's a description, "%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09Take%20control%20of%20your%20own%20starship%20in%20a%20cutthroat%20galaxy.%20Elite%3A%20Dangerous%20brings%20gaming%E2%u20AC%u2122s%20original%20open%20world%20adventure%20into%20the%20modern%20generation%20with%20a%20connected%20galaxy%2C%20evolving%20narrative%20and%20the%20entirety%20of%20the%20Milky%20Way%20re-created%20at%20its%20full%20galactic%20proportions.%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09", which cannot be decoded, I get error "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed"